# Ricky McCormick's Notes

Tags: cipher, real, unsolved-mysteries

On June 30 1999, [Ricky McCormick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricky_McCormick%27s_encrypted_notes) was found dead in an isolated area, 15 miles away from his home. He didn't own a car, and the area was not subjected to public transport so it is a mystery how he got there. The case has been identified as a murder, not a suicide as was first suggested.

Found in his pockets where two notes, seemingly encoded. The FBI, and other services, have tried decoding the notes unsuccessfully. The FBI has posted it online asking for help. If they have investigated it, and then asked for help, we can assume it's not just a case of bad spelling and handwriting. The notes are believed to tell us why he was murdered.

No-one has solved this mystery in 17 years....

**Maybe one of *you* can?**

Here are the notes:

Note 1:

[image]

```
P1    
(MND MKNE M RSE-N-S-M-KNARE) (ACSM)    
TFRNE NPINSE NPBSE RCB RNSE NPRSE INC    
PRSE N MRSE OPRE HLD WLD NCBE (TFXLF TCXLF NCBE)    
AL-PR PPI T XLY PPIY NCBE MGKSE WLD RCB RNSE PRSE   
WLD RCB RNSE NT SSNE NTKSE-CRSLE-CITRSE WLD NCBE    
AL WLD NCBE TSME LRSE RLSE U R GLSNE AS N WLD NCBE    
(NOPFSE NLSRE NCBE) NTE G D DMN SENCURE RCBRNE    
(TENE TFRNE NCBRTSE NCBE INC)    
(FLRSE PRSE ON DE 71 NCBE)    
(CDNSE PRSE ON SFE 74 NCBE)    
(PR+SE PRSE ON REDE 75 NCBE)    
(TF NRCMSP SOLE MRDE LUSE TOTE WLD N WLD NCBE)    
(194 WLD’S NCBE) (TRFXL)
```

Note 2:

[image]

```
ALPNTE GLSE – SE ER+E
VLSE MTSE-CTSE-WSE-FRTSE
PNRTRSE ONDRSE WLD NCBE
N WLD XLRCMSP NE WLD S TS MEXL
DULMT 6 TUNSE NCBEXC
(MUNSARSTEN MU NARSE)
KLSE-LRSTE-TRSE-TRSE-MKSEN-MRSE
(SAEG NSE SE N MRSE)
NMNRCBRNSEP+E 2PTEWSRCBKNSE
26 MLSE 74 SPRKSE 29KCNOS OLE 175 RTRSE
35 SLE CLGSE UUNUTKEDKRSE PSESHLE
651 MTCSE HTLSE NCUTC TRS NMRE
99.84.52 UNEPLSENCRSEAOLTSENSKSENRSE
NSREONSE PUTSEWLD NCBE (3 XORL)
DNMSE NRSE 1N2 NTRLERC BRNSE NTSRCRSNE
LSPNSE N GSPSE MKSE RBSE NEBE AU XL 'R
HM CRE N MRE NCBE 1/2 MUNDDLSE
D-W-M-4 HPL XDRLX
```

**Good luck...**

Comment: I've searched online for a csv version but haven't found one

Comment: too many SE in the notes, sounds like junk note to me.

Comment: @Oray, it is believed not. There is parts of english in there as well, for instance note 1 has 'first person' in brackets

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, as far as I could read online, he was just not very good at writing. So it is not really enciphered, more like extremely bad spelling. And when you add to that bad handwriting, it would be very difficult to make something out of it.

Comment: @MD, the FBI have investigated it and said it is a cipher. They have posted it online asking for help. I think if it was just bad spelling then they'd have realised that and not asked for help

Comment: I assume the reference to 'first person' is the part that says "FI(?)RSEPRSEON" (and so the next line which says "CDNSEPRSEON" probably means 'second person').

Comment: ACSM might be AC5M or AL5M first line first note...

Comment: Is this transcription somehow "official"? Some letters are certainly ambiguous. Also, it might be important to reproduce the capitalization.

Comment: I see lots of parentheses, so it's probably some Lisp code. ;-)

Comment: I've been wondering if it might be some kind of personal shorthand? It might explain why it's so incomprehensible years later, as well as some of the repeated abbreviations like WLD and NCBE

Answer (score 6):

I will say that reading this at an hour past midnight, out in a small somewhat rural area, is definitely creepy!  Poor Ricky.

!!! This answer is being presented as a ‘work in progress’.

First, the transcriptions provided seem to be rather careless, I must say.  I will here provide new versions here.  Given the shorthandish nature of the letters, and the inconsistent sizes of letter case, I will not transcribe diffferences of uppercase and lowercase.  Written–over letters will be signified by the use of *slant* formatting.  Questionable letters by **bold** formatting and so as to make them more visible, and parallel possibilities by special curly-brace notation.  Be advised that I never transcribed any of these from the Notes:

```
{ } | ? , *
```

(There are a few places where the parser for the preview failed to render some formatting.)

### note 2, block 1

> ALPNTE GLSE - SE ER+E
>
> VLSE MTSE-CTSE-*L*WSE-FRTSE
>
> PN*T*RTRSEON{**D**|**P**}*K*RSEWLD NCBE
>
> NWLDXLRCMSP NEWLDSTSMEXL
>
> *P*DULMT6TUNSE NC{**R**|**B**}EX{**L**|**C**}

### note 2, block 2

> ({***A***|*N*}M*U*LNSAISTENMU NARSE)
>
> {***(***|***L***}KLSE-LKSTE-TRSE-TRSE-M*T*{**L**|**K**}SE N-MLSE
>
> (SAE{**B**|**6**}NSE SE N MBSE)

### note 2, block 3

> NMN *R*LCB R NSE P+E 2PTWSRC BK**N**{**X**|**S**}E
>
> **2**6 MLSE 74SPRKS E 29*C*KC NO{***3***|***L***}{**S**|**8**}OLE I7SR7RSE
>
> 3S{***S***|***5***}6LE CL**G**SE {**J**|**U**}UNUT{**X**|**K**}E*P*DKRSE PSESHLE
>
> 6SI MTCSE HTLSE N CUTCTRS NM**R**E
>
> 99.84**S** 2UNE P LSE{**N**|**V**}CRSE***P***AO**R**TSENS**K**SEN{???;***B***,***L***,***S***} SE
>
> NSREONSE {**P**|**D**}VTSEWLD**N** CBE (3X**O**RL)

### note 2, block 4

> *L*DNMSE NRSE I N2 N TR{**L**|**C**}ERCB**A**NSE **N**TSRCRS N E
>
> LSPNSE N GSPSE MKSE R BSENEBE A{**U**|**V**} XLR
>
> HM CR E N MRE **N**{**C**|**L**}BE 1/2MUNDDLSE

### note 2, block 5

> D-W-M-4 H{**P**|**B**}L XDRLX

Regarding this Note 2, it seems that the scribe was becoming increasingly distressed with each additional block.  Alas, the handwriting also invites several other possible interpretations.

Also, why is block 4 not complete?  That right tip is missing; did Ricky draw the bubble like that?  It's a toss–up as to whether I would've ended such a bubble on the edge of the paper or made loose lines, but I think it would be more likely that I'd squeeze the remaining letters and neatly round the edge of the bubble.

Given the similarity of the lettering and that presumption, I do not see it very likely that the blocks were written by different scribes imitating the original style.

I have a hunch that these notes were a journal of the scribe, made of travels planned or performed.

I strongly doubt that it was a cipher, unless he was paranoid or trained as a spy of some sort.
There's no reason to take blind faith in anything anyone does, whether they belong to some group known as the FBI or not.  If only they'd released the Notes sooner . . .
In 2012 an interview with the family seems to cast a savantic light on Ricky.  His ability to spell in accepted english was remarked as being poor or nonextant.  He was described as being imaginative and with a penchant for the fantastic.  The word ‘schizophrenic’ was used, but it did not say that he was clinically given that label by a psychiatrist.

It first seems to me like the scribe was encoding directions, locations, and distances in Note 1.

```
ALPNTE    ALton PoiNT East
GLSE      Green L South East
```

Et cetera.

However, the repetition of certain strings, e.g

> TRSE
>
> MLSE

makes it unlikely that such strings are simple places.

Comment: It's a partial answer at least, albeit without much content yet. But since this is a real-life unsolved mystery which even the FBI couldn't solve, a complete answer might be too much to expect. I'll err on the side of *not* deleting this.

Comment: I suppose I should've made that clearer when I said “I will update this answer as I produce ideas.”  Thanks for the vote of confidence!  :-P